# removing jsapi and using jquery lib instead

Tags: jquery-plugins, jsapi

Would anyone know if removing `<script src='http://www.google.com/jsapi' type='text/javascript'></script>` would be ok if still running `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`?

The jsapi is from the adsense code and just wondering if everything that relies on it including adsense would still function with only jquery 1.11.2.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fair bit of testing it turns out that it works fine off just jquery 1.11.2. Clicks have been registering so didn't lose any earnings during the testing period.